# How to get the usage size for each partition of Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

How to get the usage size for each partition of Azure Cosmos DB?

I would like to get the usage size for each partition of Cosmos DB.

I ran Rest API according to the following site, but I get the following error.

```sh
curl -X GET -L -H "Content-Type: application / json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxx" https://{account}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db}/colls/ {collection}
```

> {"code": "BadRequest", "message": "Invalid API version. Ensure a valid x-ms-version header value is passed. Please update to the latest version of Azure Cosmos DB SDK. \ r \ nActivityId: 9993e774- 4b66-4ba0-b71b-2f4ad0edc754, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0 "}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-cosmos-db

I'm trying to get the partition size with Azure Java Cosmos SDK v4, but I don't have the following class that was in SDK v2, so I don't know which class to use in v4.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.partitionkeystatistics?view=azure-java-stable

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Just a side-note: if you are sending a GET, you don't need a `Content-Type` header, but you probably want an `Accept` header. So change it to `-H "Accept: application/json"`

Comment: And it's complaining because you don't fill out the `x-ms-version` header. So you want to add another `-H` argument. It will look like: `-H "x-ms-version: 4.0.0"`. I don't know what the version number is supposed to be formatted as. You'll have to look that up.